# zero inflated model in R, building the model with pscl, not understanding use of ' | 1'

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, poisson-regression, computational-statistics, zero-inflation

I have count data with lots of zero. I have done a GLM with poisson distribution, and I think that using the zero inflated model might improve the fit. Now my problem, I have been working with SPSS. This does not have the zero inflated model build in, and using the R extension did not work. So I have moved to R completely. But I have problem building the model.

I found the pscl package, which can perform zero-inflated Poisson regression. What I want to test are main effects for variable 1 and variable2 and an interaction between them. Plot is a fixed factor.

First I ran a normal poisson distributed model

```
mod1 = glm(count ~Plot + var1+var2 + var1*var2, family= poisson)
```

This worked fine. Now for the zeroinfl.

I checked the ?zeroinfl and I saw some things which confuse me. Namely the use of | and |1.

var1 and var2 have 2 levels, and in my data therefore have a value 1 or 2 as seen below. This is just an example and there are more plots. But every combination of var1 and var2 has the same probability of having count zero.

```
plot    Var1    Var2    count
1       1        1      0
1       1        2      1
1       2        1      2
1       1        2      0
```

Now I tried it like this.

```
zeroinfl(n ~ Plot + var1+var2 + var1*var2|1, data = dat)
```

But I don't think it is correct. I only get an intercept in the zero distributed output, and not the main effects and interaction. Also the zeroinfl does a normal poisson glm and the values differ from my spss output.

So, can anyone help/give me some tips on how to build the model correctly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How many observations would be enough for such a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the zero-inflated, the zero counts can come from either a process that generates zero or a process that generates counts, in your case, it is a poisson. In pscl, after the "|" , you specify how you want to model the process that generates zeros.

A good place to start is this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf), so I will quote a part from there with some added explanation.

The zero-inflated density is a mixture of a point mass at zero $I_{0}
(y)$ and a count distribution $f_{count}(y; x,\beta)$. The probability of observing a zero count is inflated with probability $\pi = f_{zero} (0; z,\gamma)$:

$$f_{zeroinfl}(y; x, z, \beta,\gamma) = f_{zero}(0; z,\gamma) · I_{0}(y) + (1 − f_{zero}(0; z, \gamma)) · f_{count}(y; x, \beta)$$

Normally the model that generates zero, is modelled by a binomial GLM where the mean is

$$\mu_i = \pi_i· 0 + (1 − \pi_i) · \exp(x_i^T\beta)$$

If you want to model the zero part with a similar equation, using the example from the package, you do:

```
library(pscl)
fm_zip2 <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | ., data = bioChemists)
fm_zip2

Call:
zeroinfl(formula = art ~ . | ., data = bioChemists)

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
(Intercept)     femWomen   marMarried         kid5          phd         ment  
   0.640839    -0.209144     0.103750    -0.143320    -0.006166     0.018098  

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
(Intercept)     femWomen   marMarried         kid5          phd         ment  
  -0.577060     0.109752    -0.354018     0.217095     0.001275    -0.134114
```

For your example, if you do:

```
zeroinfl(n ~ Plot + var1+var2 + var1*var2|1, data = dat)
```

You are modeling the zero part to be missing at random with a probability that is constant. If you believe your zero values are also dependent on the other variables, you can do:

```
zeroinfl(n ~ Plot + var1+var2 + var1*var2|Plot + var1+var2 + var1*var2, data = dat)
```

But before going to such a complicated model, it makes sense to check whether you have enough observations to model this? And also whether there is reason to model it like this